# How to install Ubuntu on a Mac with a broken disk drive?

Tags: mac, macbook

The drive spits out any disk I insert, and I can't use Unetbootin drives. How can I install Ubuntu without using a disk/drive on a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Make a bootable USB drive, and install from that. There are instructions for doing just that [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) on the Ubuntu website.

Answer (score 0):

this is probably not a good solution, but you could get the ssd out of your mac, put it in another computer, install ubuntu, put it back into your mac.